# Trying to combine 2 vars but getting: mergedObject is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to combine the 2 objects and save them to the collection. But as I'm really new to Node.js/Express I think I'm missing something. All advice is welcome!

Thx in advance for your precious time.

This is what I puzzled together but ***doesn't*** work:

```
app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.address.street + req.body.address.no + req.body.address.zip + req.body.address.city, function(req, res) {
    var gpslocation = ({"loc": [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude]});
    mergedObject = JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(object) + JSON.stringify(gpslocation)).replace(/}{/g,","))
    console.log(mergedObject);
    });
    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(error,docs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(201, docs);} //B
   });
});
```

output(console.log) but actual save is working but not with the longitude/latitude appended to it:

```
{ cat: 'Electrician6',
name: { first: 'John', last: 'Pipe', picture_ID: '23872' },
created_at: '2015-05-16T14:05:23.431Z',
_id: '55574ea3435c2d9c24d21572',
loc: [ 4.7261822, 50.9635574 ] }
```

But when I edit it to:

```
app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) { //A
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.address.street + req.body.address.no + req.body.address.zip + req.body.address.city, function(req, res) {
    var gpslocation = ({"loc": [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude]});
    mergedObject = JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(object) + JSON.stringify(gpslocation)).replace(/}{/g,","))
    console.log(mergedObject);
    });
    collectionDriver.save(collection, mergedObject, function(error,docs) {
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(201, docs);} //B
   });
});
```

output:

```
ReferenceError: mergedObject is not defined
    at app.put.params (/app/testapp/index.js:92:39)
    at callbacks (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at param (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:132:11)
    at pass (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle] (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:55:61)
    at next (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    { cat: 'Electrician6',
    name: { first: 'John', last: 'Pipe', picture_ID: '23872' },
    loc: [ 4.7261822, 50.9635574 ] }
```

Comment: You can refer this link, and see if helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to merge two objects. Just add the "loc" property to the original object. Also you need to call collectionDriver.save inside your callback so it happens only after geocoder.geocode is finished.

```
app.post('/:collection', function(req, response) {
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    geocoder.geocode(object.address.street + object.address.no + object.address.zip + object.address.city, function(req, res) {
      object.loc = [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude];
      console.log(object);
      collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(error,docs) {
        if (error) { response.send(400, error); }
        else { response.send(201, docs);}
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but I tried this approach earlier but the app craches with this error: /app/testapp/index.js:89
      object.loc = [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude];
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined
    at /app/testapp/index.js:89:27
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder.js:33:17

Comment: What error? Have you you actually tried my code?

Comment: Yes i tried it, and he saves it to the datastore a well but exits with following error: /app/testapp/index.js:89
      object.loc = [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude];
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined
    at /app/testapp/index.js:89:27
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder.js:33:17
    at Geocoder._format (/app/testapp/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder.js:149:5)
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder.js:31:15
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder/googlegeocoder.js:7<SNIP>

Comment: Put in `console.log(res)` to see what res is.

Comment: ReferenceError: res is not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at app.post.object (/app/testapp/index.js:88:17)
    at callbacks (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at param (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:132:11)
    at pass (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/testapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next ]  <SNIP>)

Comment: Put `console.log(res)` right above `object.loc = [res[0].longitude, res[0].latitude];`

Comment: Looks like its empty -> []

Comment: So sorry, was something wrong with the adres. Now getting:

Comment: now getting : /app/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'send'
    at /app/testapp/index.js:94:20
    at /app/testapp/collectionDriver.js:67:11
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:128:9
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1195:7
    at /app/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/app/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:4

Comment: but it gets saved to the datastore

Comment: But `response` should have a method `send`. Check again if your code is really identical to mine. Especially the use of `res` and `response`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was another function which was giving the error. Thanks for your patience and time!

Answer (score 0):

To merge, use the [lodash merge function](https://lodash.com/docs#merge), it does the trick